# I have evidence that someone is accessing my Google account, what should I do?

Tags: google-account, authentication

I have evidence that someone has been accessing my Google account since I started to login to use a variety of services. I did not have this problem when I was using my Google account exclusively for Gmail.

I also try not to accept the "keep me signed in option," but it remains enabled no matter how often I change my password. I feel I have no privacy at all so I want to go back to using only Gmail.

How do I do this without seeing the Google logo whenever I sign in to my account?

Comment: How do you know that someone is accessing your account?  at the bottom of your google webmail you have " Last account activity: 12 hours ago at this IP (xx.xx.xx.xx).  [link]Details"  Does that have any relevant information?

Comment: The first thing you should do is change your password. The second is to seriously consider using [two-step verification](https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/SmsAuthConfig).

Answer (score 5):

I would first change your password, and make sure it's not something easily guessed. Then I would contact Google support.

After you change your password, go to your gmail and at the bottom of the page, click "Details". You will see a pop up window that tells you who and where accessed your account. Above it is a "Sign out all other sessions" button, click that to make sure no one else is logged in as you.

I have noticed sometimes my iPhone would log as IMAP but from varying locations, sometimes not even the same state I am in...

Answer (score 2):

Contact Google Support. You know, the guys that support Google stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Do not change your password first.  Go into the security settings

Click the  gear in the top right.
Select Settings.
Click the Accounts tab.
In the "Grant access to your account" section, click delete on any account you want to remove.

If you do have someone tagging along, when you change the password, they come with you.

If you delete the "tag - along", then change the password, they are gone.

Answer (score -1):

Just check this https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

Check the IP address right side

I have check with wimax modem and broadband line. The IP is different.

Once I have shared my gdrive with password with my colleagues lives in Australia to share something like gigabyte files and I am using my gdrive from bangladesh. Google instantly report me that someone is accessing my account from somewhere else. So don't get worry too much. Google will take care of it. If you think someone is accessing your account, just change the password to satisfy yourself.